# Show system alert or notification from Swift script

Tags: swift, notifications

I want to show system alert or notification from Swift script. For example, if there are more than 30 files in Desktop folder, I want to see any kind of notifications. How I can do it?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you know and where you're stuck? I think you just have create a method which parse folder content to count number of files. Then if this number is upper to 30, use local notification to display an alert.

Comment: To drive any user interface your *script* must be an application (to take advantage of AppKit and the run loop).

Comment: Maxime, my main question is how to show local notification?

Answer (score -1):

To send a local notification, I think you just have to use this:

```
func showNotification() -> Void {
    var notification = NSUserNotification()
    notification.title = "Test from Swift"
    notification.informativeText = "The body of this Swift notification"
    notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName
    NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)
}
```

There is a [detailed tutorial here](https://nabtron.com/show-notification-cocoa-xcode-swift/)

Comment: Be aware that a  simple Swift ***script*** (command line interface) is not able to send notifications.